# Redshift driver installation on Linux

Tags: linux, odbc, amazon-redshift, unixodbc

I downloaded the 64-bit redshift odbc .rpm file. I am installing the driver for Oracle OBIEE. So, I don't want to install it system wide.

I decompressed the .rpm file to `/u01/app/oracle/product` with: `rpm2cpio AmazonRedshiftODBC-64-bit-1.4.20.1001-1.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv`

I installed unixODBC.

I added the following to `/etc/odbcinst.ini`:

```
[RedshiftDriver]
Driver=/u01/app/oracle/product/redshiftodbc/lib/64/libamazonredshiftodbc64.so
```

I added the following to `/etc/odbc.ini`:

```
[redshift]
Driver=Driver=/u01/app/oracle/product/redshiftodbc/lib/64/libamazonredshiftodbc64.so
Description=redshift
Host=<my redshift endpoint hostname>
Port=5932
Database=<my db>
locale=en-US
```

I run: `isql -v redshift <myuser> <mypass>`

I get:

```
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

I also tried the 32 bit driver. I am operating as root. The path to the .so file is correct.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Hah. Proofreading my post and see that I put:
`Driver=Driver=` in odbc.ini.

Problem solved.

Then I realized I used the wrong port. It’s supposed to be 5439.

And to top it off I realize I posted this on SO instead of server fault.

It’s been a long week.

Maybe the procedure will help someone else looking for AWS redshift driver info.